# How to use JunitTest with Camel, ActiveMQ and external API

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic, alfresco

I'm trying to set up JunitTest using camel, activeMq and an Alfresco API

The route I want to test is :

```
from(Constantes.Direct.DIRECT_GET_AUTHENTIFICATION_TICKET)
        .setBody().simple("{"
                        + "\"userId\": \"userId\","
                        +"\"password\": \"password\""
                        +"}")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,constant(Constantes.Headers.HTTP_POST))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI,simple(Constantes.Urls.OBTENIR_TICKET))
    .to(Constantes.Urls.DUMMYHOST).convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, TicketAlfresco.class).process(new Dumper())
        .process(new TokenBase64Proc())
        .setHeader(Constantes.Headers.SENDER, constant(Constantes.Headers.ALFRESCO))
        .setHeader(Constantes.Headers.API_ACTION, constant(SET_ALFRESCO_TOKEN))
        .setHeader(Constantes.Headers.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, simple("${body}"))
    .inOut(Constantes.ActiveMq.ACTIVEMQ_IN)
    .end();
```

The first "to" send a request to the Alfresco API and give back a new token.
The last inOut send the token to an activeMQ.

The problem is that when I want to test my route, when the test arrive to inOut inside the activeMq, the test fail because it didn't get any answer.

Do I need to install and embeded broker activeMQ or do I need to Mock the ActiveMQ ? And how can I do that?

For the moment to make it run I use :

```
mockEndpointsAndSkip("activemq:IN")
```

But I'm not sure that is the good solution.

Here is the test I have for the moment:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"fr.gif.wsp.web.service.alfresco*"})
```

public class RouteGetAuthentificationTicketTest extends CamelTestSupport{

```
@Autowired private RouteGetAuthentificationTicket routeGetAuthentificationTicket;

//Route to test
private final static String FOURNISSEUR_GET_AUTHENTIFICATION_TICKET = Constantes.Direct.DIRECT_GET_AUTHENTIFICATION_TICKET;
private final static String MOCK_FOURNISSEUR_GET_AUTHENTIFICATION_TICKET = "mock:" + FOURNISSEUR_GET_AUTHENTIFICATION_TICKET;
// Mock result
private final static String MOCK_RESULT = "mock:result";
//Data
private final static String BODY = "Content of the body";

@Override
protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return routeGetAuthentificationTicket; 
}

@Before
public void setContextRoute() throws Exception  {
    context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            mockEndpointsAndSkip("activemq:IN");
            weaveAddLast().to(MOCK_RESULT);
        }
    });
}

@Test
public void getAuthentificationTicket() throws InterruptedException {

    final MockEndpoint resultEndpoint = context.getEndpoint(MOCK_FOURNISSEUR_GET_AUTHENTIFICATION_TICKET, MockEndpoint.class);

    context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody(FOURNISSEUR_GET_AUTHENTIFICATION_TICKET, BODY);
    resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();

    final Object result = context.createProducerTemplate().requestBody(FOURNISSEUR_GET_AUTHENTIFICATION_TICKET, BODY);
    assertNotNull(result);
}}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Just mock the activemq part and return the actual message you expect. If you really want to use activemq I guess you either use an embedded one or use docker to start an activemq docker container to use for your tests.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Souciance Eqdam Rashti,
Is it correct to mock the activemq like this : 
weaveByToString(".*activemq:IN.*").replace().to("mock:activemq:IN"); ?
or is there another way to do it?

Comment: You can do that or just replace it with a complete string containing your actual response message...replace().body("yourbody") or similar.

Comment: Thanks @Souciance Eqdam Rashti for your answer, it's seems to work!

Comment: The Camel in Action book in the testing chapter talks about different strategies as well for testing with and simulating real systems.